# My sticky element is stuck inside the div

Tags: html, css

I am starting to use html and my father asked me to make him a website for his company.
but i found a problem i have encountered allot of time.

the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <header>
        <style>

            #div_head {
                background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);
                height: 300px;
                width: auto;
            }

            #div_text {
                text-align: center;
                font-family: Helvetica;
                color: black;
                margin: 0 auto;
                height: fit-content;
                width: fit-content;
                padding-top: 5px;
                padding-bottom: 5px;
                padding-right: 7px;
                padding-left: 7px;
                font-size: 400%;
                top: 5px;
                background-color: grey;
                border-radius: 15px;
            }

        </style>
    </header>
    <body>
            <div id="div_head">
                <div id="div_text" style="position: sticky;">
                    MEET INFRA
                </div>
            </div>
(this is so i can scroll)
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
</html>
```

as you can see is that the div_text is inside of the div_head (dont ask why i called it that idk why) and it cant get out of it.

so if someone could help me figure out how i can get the div_text follow the scroll on the entire page.

Comment: I never used `position : 'sticky'` try `position:'fixed'` , it should do what you expect

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/

Comment: *"My sticky element is stuck inside the div"* - title sounds like it's working as expected :P

Comment: *" div_text is inside of the div_head (dont ask why i called it that idk why) and it cant get out of it."* - so you don't want the text to go behind the sticky header?

Answer (score 0):

Check out just positioning will work and parent had only `300px` in your case.So its been sticky for `300px`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <header>
        <style>

            #div_head {
                background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);
                height: 100%;
                width: auto;
            }

            #div_text {
                text-align: center;
                font-family: Helvetica;
                color: black;
                margin: 0 auto;
                height: fit-content;
                width: fit-content;
                padding-top: 5px;
                padding-bottom: 5px;
                padding-right: 7px;
                padding-left: 7px;
                font-size: 400%;
                top: 5px;
                background-color: grey;
                border-radius: 15px;
                z-index:5;       
                position:sticky;
            }

        </style>
    </header>
    <body>
            <div id="div_head">
                <div id="div_text" >
                    MEET INFRA
                </div>
              (this is so i can scroll)
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
     </div>
     </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make the bbb elements scroll try this :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <header>
        <style>

            #div_head {
                background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);
                height: 300px;
                width: auto;
            }

            #div_text {
                text-align: center;
                font-family: Helvetica;
                color: black;
                margin: 0 auto;
                height: fit-content;
                width: fit-content;
                padding-top: 5px;
                padding-bottom: 5px;
                padding-right: 7px;
                padding-left: 7px;
                font-size: 400%;
                top: 5px;
                background-color: grey;
                border-radius: 15px;
            }
            .scroll {
                 overflow: scroll;
                 border: 5px solid black;
                 height: 800px;
            } /* this is the style to do scroll*/

        </style>
    </header>
    <body>
            <div id="div_head">
                <div id="div_text" style="position: sticky;">
                    MEET INFRA
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="scroll">
(this is so i can scroll)
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
    </div>
</body>/*you forget to add this*/
</html>
```

and if you want the div id="div_text" to follow use `postion:fixed;` on it

Answer (score 0):

You need get the sticky text out from header div like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>

<style>
#div_head {
  background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

#div_text {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-right: 7px;
  padding-left: 7px;
  font-size: 400%;
  top: 5px;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 15px;
  z-index: 1;
}
</style>

</header>

<body>

<div id="div_text" style="position: sticky; top: 0;">
  MEET INFRA
</div>

<div id="div_head"></div>

<div style="margin-top: 300px;">
(this is so i can scroll)
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
        bbbbb <br>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

or just use "fixed" instead "sticky":

```
<div id="div_text" style="position: fixed; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);">
```